# How to join multiple tables effectively SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, syntax-error, inner-join

I am encountering a syntax error when attempting to join tables in my SQL query. Here's the context:

I have the following tables

- tblGeneral (ID, DestinationID, OriginID)
- tblDestinations (DestinationID, DestinationName)
- tblPrices (OriginID, OriginName, Africa, Asia, China)

I want to use the DestinationID in tblGeneral, to get the relevant price from tblPrices
Eg. a sample row of tblDestinations:

| DestinationID | DestinationName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Africa |

I want to get the DestinationName and use that to reference the column in tblPrices (in this case Africa)

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
    tblGeneral.ID AS ID, tblDestinations.DestinationName AS Destination, tblPrices.OriginName AS Origin,
    SWITCH(
        tblDestinations.DestinationName = "Africa", tblPrices.Africa,
        tblDestinations.DestinationName = "Asia", tblPrices.Asia,
        tblDestinations.DestinationName = "China", tblPrices.China
    ) AS Price
FROM 
    tblGeneral
INNER JOIN 
    tblDestinations ON tblGeneral.DestinationID = tblDestinations.DestinationID
INNER JOIN 
    tblPrices ON tblGeneral.OriginID = tblPrices.OriginID;
```

I expect something like this as output:

| ID | Destination | Origin | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Africa | Brazil | $57.90 |

However I get `Syntax error - Missing operator`.
I've tried adjusting the join conditions and reviewing the query syntax, but I'm unable to resolve the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean ```... tblDestinations.DestinationName AS Destination, ...``` ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was just a typo on my side

Comment: Access has strange multiple join syntax. Extra parentheses required.

Comment: Use Access query designer to get correct syntax.